# SQL - Duplicating data across matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a fairly easy SQL task at hand and I'd like validation (or guidance) for the solution I came up with. Thank you for helping! (this is my first post)

Here's the problem I'm facing (simplified):

I'm importing user information from a flat file into a staging table (using SSIS). Each user will have 2 or 3 records. Each line will contain important data. The end result needs to be 1 record per customer that contains info from all 3.

Here's an example of the data:

```
PK |    Name   | UniqueCustID | Info1 | Info2  | Info3 |
----------------------
1   | John Doe  |    12345     |  Opt1  |  NULL |  NULL
2   | John Doe  |    12345     |  NULL  |  Opt2 |  NULL
3   | John Doe  |    12345     |  NULL  |  NULL |  Opt3
```

The final result needs be be something like this:

```
 PK |    Name   | UniqueCustID | Info1 | Info2  | Info3 |
----------------------
1   | John Doe  |    12345     |  Opt1  |  Opt2 |  Opt3
```

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible. I want to handle this with a basic Execute SQL task in SSIS (or a couple). What are people's jump-to reactions? Can I provide any additional information? Thank you again.

**UPDATE** - To show the two step process I am trying:

1) This *should* make all of the individual customer sets match:

```
WITH CustInfoTMP (UniqueCustID,Info1,Info2,Info3)
AS
    (
    SELECT UniqueCustID,MAX(Info1),MAX(Info2),MAX(Info3)
    FROM CustStaging
    GROUP BY UniqueCustID 
    )
UPDATE CustStaging 
SET 
    CustStaging.Info1 = CustInfoTMP.Info1
    CustStaging.Info2 = CustInfoTMP.Info2
    CustStaging.Info3 = CustInfoTMP.Info3
FROM CustStaging
INNER JOIN CustStagingTMP ON CustStaging.UniqueCustID = CustStagingTMP.UniqueCustID
```

2) I then using this to delete duplicate records:

```
DELETE
FROM CustStaging 
WHERE UniqueCustID NOT IN
    (
    SELECT MAX(PK) 
    FROM CustStaging 
    GROUP BY UniqueCustID
    )
```

I hope everyone is following this. I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: What do you want if row 2 has `Opt4` in the `Info1` column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - That's a great question, which I haven't thought about. For now, we can assume that information in Info1/info2/info3 columns will always be identical for the same customers.

Comment: Is that an answer? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @RedFilter - I might have to update my original post to show you what I'm doing. I create a temp table using the WITH clause (think it's called a CTE) and then update the staging table so that each set of customer records matches. I then delete duplicated.

Comment: Sorry Aaron. I think I pressed enter before finishing the comment. Hopefully I answered your question now.

Comment: @RedFilter - I updated my OP so show what  I'm currently doing. In testing this has worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
CREATE TABLE TargetTable_tbl
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
  Name  varchar(100),
  Info1 varchar(10),
  Info2 varchar(10),
  Info3 varchar(10)
)
go

insert TargetTable_tbl 

select distinct Name, Info1, Info2, Info3
from StagingTable_tbl ST
left join 
( select distinct Name, Info1
  from StagingTable_tbl 
  where Info1 is not null ) I1 on ST.Name = I1.Name
left join 
( select distinct Name, Info2
  from StagingTable_tbl 
  where Info2 is not null ) I2 on ST.Name = I2.Name
left join 
( select distinct Name, Info3
  from StagingTable_tbl 
  where Info3 is not null ) I3 on ST.Name = I3.Name
go
```

Comment: So this solution would keep the staging table as is and then correct them in the insert to the final table. I have no idea why I didn't think about this, haha (I guess that's why I asked!). This makes more logical sense to me than what I choose (I am attempting to update the staging table before insert)

Answer (score 3):

use the max function, it will eliminate the nulls:

```
select min(id), UniqueCustID, name, max (Opt1), max(Opt2), max(Opt3)
from TABLE
group by UniqueCustID, name
```

Comment: You forgot the "Name" column. Add that to the select column list and group by, and you're done.

Comment: @Diego / Philip - This is kind of what I'm doing. Thank you. Once I have grouped the records, how would you suggest I update? I import the records in the raw format, so this select statement should be a result of an update.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
select a.name, a.uniqueCustID,
a.info1, b.info2, c.info3
from table1 a
left outer join table1 b on b.pk = a.pk and b.info1 is not null
left outer join table1 c on c.pk = a.pk and c.info2 is not null
```

The left outer joins are needed because you don't know in advance if a user will have 1, 2 or 3 records with data. This way, if there is no data, a null will be inserted in the corresponding field.

Comment: I read things similar to this. This is basically joining a table to itself, correct? At the time I wasn't able to wrap my head around this, so I used what google told me! I'll also have to try this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's called a self-join.